# Reason for calling setEnabled(false) in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am working on Swing for a while now but never had a situation in practice when I had to call `setEnabled(false)` in `JPanel`. 
Still, I see such code sometimes in some sophisticated gui. But I really don't undarstand why someone wants to use it?
So, please give me some examples of real life common situations when you need to use `setEnabled(false)` on `JPanel`.

Also in javadoc it says:

> Disabling a component does not disable its children.

actually I had a bug because table inside disabled `JPanel` didn't show mouse resize cursor when resizing columns. I suspect there are other unpleasant surprises here.

Comment: I believe that you can disable a top-level window this way, but not a container

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels : still JPanel has such method. For me it looks like completely useless source of potential bugs here. But maybe I am mistaking and it has some practical usage for JPanel.

Comment: Working with swing is like death from a thousand cuts.  A method that does nothing?  really?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One reason is so that getEnabled() will reflect the correct state.
Consider a case where some event handler wants to flag the panel 
as no longer enabled and it is not prudent at the time of the event 
to iterate over and disable all child components.  Other parts of the
app might need to test the state of the panel via getEnabled() to
determine what to do at different points in the app.

I personally never had to do this but now that you asked and got me
thinking I might use this sometime. Thanks.  &&+=1 to the question.

Comment: I guess in case when you disable all children this is a valid usage. Otherwise it may lead to bugs similar to one described in my question. Great example by the way. It's a pity Swing has no way to disable all children of a component in one line of code though.

Comment: A setEnabledAll() in a utils class would be easy enough.  I'll add one incase someone needs to see how it would be done.

Comment: A simple state flag doesn't have much value without associated desired behaviour. your `setEnabledAll()` seems an obvious extension to JPanel (or more generally to any view element, like Component).  I keep finding head scratchers like this in Swing.

Answer (score 5):

Starter code to enable/disable all components in a container.

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setEnabled(state);
setEnabledAll(p, state);

public void setEnabledAll(Object object, boolean state) {
    if (object instanceof Container) {
        Container c = (Container)object;
        Component[] components = c.getComponents();
        for (Component component : components) {
            setEnabledAll(component, state);
            component.setEnabled(state);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (object instanceof Component) {
            Component component = (Component)object;
            component.setEnabled(state);
        }
    }
}
```