# Blocking Swing input without using modal dialog

Tags: java, swing, focus

*I want to block input to a window, but still be able to move it.*

If there was a modal dialog type allowing the window that spawned it to move, then I would be happy.

Say I have a window that opens another window. This second window then opens a modal dialog, which blocks input to the other two windows (fine), but also locks these two windows in place (why - Amigas didn't do this :) ?).

My problem is that I may need to visually read something in the first window for use in the dialog, but this may not be possible because the second window is locked in place, covering it.

I have almost solved this with glass panes, I think. I set the class below to be the glass pane of the root pane of my window, then I call setVisible(true) on it when I want to block and setVisible(false) when I want to unlock the window. When locked, the window greys out to indicate this.

Mouse input is blocked except for closing the window which is fine for now - the problem is that I can still tab around the components on the blocked window and if I get to an editable one, I can edit it with the keyboard, regardless of my empty KeyListener.

*Is there an easy way I can prevent the components behind the glass pane from gaining focus?*

I am hoping it can be done on the "InputSink" class itself.

I have tried adding its own selfish focus traversal policy and requesting focus when it is visible, but this has no effect.

I have also tried an example I found where a FocusListener was added, whose focusLost method requests focus if the glass pane is visible, but that is overkill, as the window then always stays at front.

Does anybody know a solution in between those two extremes? This is what I have:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FocusTraversalPolicy;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;

import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class InputSink extends JPanel {


public InputSink() {
    this(0.2f); //Default opacity.
}
public InputSink(float alpha) {
    setOpaque(false);
    setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, alpha)); //Just store it here.
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {});
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {});
    setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalPolicy() {
        @Override
        public Component getLastComponent(Container aContainer) {
            return InputSink.this;
        }
        @Override
        public Component getFirstComponent(Container aContainer) {
            return InputSink.this;
        }
        @Override
        public Component getDefaultComponent(Container aContainer) {
            return InputSink.this;
        }
        @Override
        public Component getComponentBefore(Container aContainer, Component aComponent) {
            return InputSink.this;
        }
        @Override
        public Component getComponentAfter(Container aContainer, Component aComponent) {
            return InputSink.this;
        }
    });
}

public void paintComponent(final Graphics gfx) { //Handle grey-out.
    gfx.setColor(getBackground());
    Rectangle rect = gfx.getClipBounds();
    gfx.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
}


@Override
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    super.setVisible(visible);
    if (visible)
        requestFocus();
}

}
```

So the version I used following Guillaume Polet's suggestion was

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class InputSink extends JPanel {

KeyEventDispatcher blockingDispatcher = new KeyEventDispatcher() {
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        return InputSink.this == ((JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor((Component) e.getSource())).getGlassPane(); //Consume!
    }
};

public InputSink) {
    this(0.2f); //Default opacity.
}
public InputSinkfloat alpha) {
    setOpaque(false);
    setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, alpha)); //Just store it here.
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {});
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {});
}

public void paintComponent(final Graphics gfx) { //Handle grey-out.
    gfx.setColor(getBackground());
    Rectangle rect = gfx.getClipBounds();
    gfx.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
}

@Override
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    super.setVisible(visible);
    if (visible)
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(blockingDispatcher);
    else
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().removeKeyEventDispatcher(blockingDispatcher);
}

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't your application copy the data from the first window to the dialog?

Comment: I need to make a (human) decision and enter something in the dialog based on what I can read in the first window. The second window is in front of it and if it opens a modal dialog, then I cannot move the second window or the first window, so if the bit I need is behind the second window, I need to close the dialog, move the second window, cut/paste, write down or memorise the value(s) in question and then open the dialog again.

Comment: I understand.  Copy the information you need to make a (human) decision from the first window into the dialog.  Why do you have 2 windows instead of 2 panels within one window?  Two panels withing one window would solve the overlap problem.

Comment: And I guess this would be one answer to the question under "Related" to the right: "Why are modal dialog boxes evil?"..

Comment: Gilbert - to reply: This is how our program is set up. There is a main window (first window), from which you start operations. The operations then display a live flowchart of progress in a second window. This flowchart window then opens modal dialogs when it needs input. Unfortunately the input sometimes depends on something in the main window.

Comment: To reply to both your comments.  Modal dialogs are supposed to be used to gather small bits of information.  Think of a login dialog as a typical example.  I don't know how much you can modify your application, but the least you could do is make sure the flowchart window doesn't overlap the start window.  Better would be to make the start and flowchart panels within one window.  Best would be, all of the above and, as I've said, for the information you need to be on the dialogs, so you don't have to refer to anything else.

Comment: I see your point, but the flowcharts don't necessarily fit well into the other window; there may also be more than one of them.

Comment: Sorry, comment edit timed out. In some cases we could probably guess the info to provide, but not always. I understand your point, but I think we should be left the choice of docking or undocking the flow charts (they are vector scalable, so could probably fit in a dock in many cases). But to me the problem is the forced locking of the other window positions - as a previous Amiga user (old chestnut), I cannot see any real problem with modal dialogs blocking input, but not _locking_ window positions. In other words I cannot see why Swing or Windows should not allow us to make a choice there.

Comment: This is going to be my last comment, as the system is bugging me to move this to chat.  Look at the Tab Pane for multiple flowchart panels.  What you have is not a Swing issue, but a user interface issue.  I hope for your users sake, you can streamline the user interface.

Comment: Same here - thank you for your comments. I think it best not to try to squeeze all the charts into one window or tab stack in general, but you did give me another idea. What I can perhaps do is persuade the person doing the flowchart windows to show most of the dialogs in the flowchart window itself and hence not make a modal popup. I still don't think the OS or windowing toolkit should force locking of window positions for modal dialogs though.

Comment: See the post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730520/reason-for-calling-setenabledfalse-in-jpanel Someone provides a method iteratively disables all the components within a Container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `KeyEventDispatcher` to the `KeyboardFocusManager` to block keyboard input.

Small demo below:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TestGlassPane {

    private static final int COUNTDOWN = 10;

    private static final String CLICK_ME = "Click me";

    private static final Color GRAY = new Color(192, 192, 192, 128);

    private JFrame frame;

    private JButton button;

    private Timer timer;

    private int countdown;

    private KeyEventDispatcher blockingDispatcher;

    private static class GrayPanel extends JComponent {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(GRAY);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }

    public TestGlassPane() {
        blockingDispatcher = new KeyEventDispatcher() {

            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        };

    }

    protected void initUI() {
        frame = new JFrame(TestGlassPane.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        button = new JButton(CLICK_ME);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                blockUserInput();
            }
        });
        GrayPanel glassPane = new GrayPanel();
        glassPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        });
        frame.setGlassPane(glassPane);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void blockUserInput() {
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(blockingDispatcher);
        frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
        countdown = COUNTDOWN;
        timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                countdown--;
                if (countdown == 0) {
                    timer.stop();
                    frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(false);
                    button.setText(CLICK_ME);
                    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().removeKeyEventDispatcher(blockingDispatcher);
                } else {
                    button.setText("We will be back in " + countdown + " seconds");
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestGlassPane().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Normally, the button can be activated with the <kbd>Space</kbd> key, but you will see that it actually gets blocked.

Comment: This works if I filter with something like: `return InputSink.this == ((JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor((Component) e.getSource())).getGlassPane();` instead of just returning true in the KeyEventDispatcher (probably implicit in you calling it a demo!).

Answer (score 1):

> because the second window is locked in place

the JDialog has always been 'moveable' for me (using windows).

another possibility to block input:

when you show your non-modal dialog, include this line

```
frame.setEnabled(false);
```

also add a windowListener to the dialog, so that on closing

```
frame.setEnabled(true);
```

seems to work OK on windows, other platforms unknown

Comment: If I add  'frame.setEnabled(!visible);' in the setVisible(boolean) method on my InputSink, and the frame is the JFrame to which the InputSink is set as glass panel, input is fully blocked, _but_ while blocking, the window is also locked in place because it cannot be selected for movement.. (this is currently being tested under Windows 7)?