# lock the swing application software on a shortcut key

Tags: java, swing, awt

In swing application i want to lock the whole running application . On a shortcut key i want the swing application should be locked as we can lock window by pressing window+l

```
user should also not be allowed to go to open forms with the help of status bar
```

Comment: make them press window-l? Other than that, probably not possible in pure java, you'll need to look for some jni code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a static variable `IS_LOCKED` in some class and in a key press event, set it to `true`. In each event, check that static variable.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [Keybindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) on the root pane of your application window to catch the shortcut event.
2. In the action of the key binding, set the glass pane of the window to visible to catch all keyboard and mouse events. Check out how to use [glass pane tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html). See also this post which shows [how to block keyboard events.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14381988/928711)